# Quick lookup in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, file, lua, benchmarking

I have a MySQl table with millions of rows, with an id as PK, which are randomly generated 32 digit numbers.
I am performing a benchmarking on this setup (using custom sysbench), and trying to test point queries. Since I can't generate Ids at random for lookup, I can think of 2 ways to do it:

1. Save the rows in file during the insertion of data, read the Ids from this file and do a lookup.
2. Keep the data which I have inserted in DB in memory, so that my benchmarking results are less skewed.

Are there any better ways to achieve this?
How can 2nd be achieved?

Comment: You could use mysql-indexes:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: I wonder if you could find a linear congruential generator (google it) + starting point that happened to generate a short sequence of valid IDs.  You could try a bunch of LCG parameters and look for longest string hits with that sequence of IDs.  Then maybe save those IDs and LCG params and use that to feed a benchmark?  Or wait, did you mean 32 *decimal* digits, not 32 bit numbers?  NVM, "millions" is such a negligible fraction of that, and running a BigInteger LCG probably would cost a non-negligible amount of CPU time even if you could find some sequences.

Comment: Yeah, reading IDs from a file sounds like the way to go.  Make sure you warm up the disk cache for it, or load it into memory before starting the clock on your benchmark, depending on what you're trying to test with your benchmark.  (And whether that will limit the amount of free memory for caching of the MySQL db.)

Comment: `select ... from tbl where id > r limit 1`. Its a b-tree search anyway.

Comment: You can load all the id's into memory, it will take a GB or two - not a huge deal.